# Microsoft Web Platform Installer wouldn't run

Tags: web-platform-installer

I just downloaded and installed the Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0 and when I hit run it pops the following error message

'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 45, position 288

Can anybody explain what is this?

I'm on Windows 10 x64

Comment: If you try downloading and running it a second time it might work.

Comment: Actually, I didn't try to download it again. I did try to run it like three more times and now, all of a sudden it's working

Comment: im getting the same thing right now, dont know what to do

Comment: just keep trying to run it. Eventually, it will. It was the same thing, both on my dev machine and in my test machine. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't understand why, but I tried to run it like three times and now it works

Answer (score -1):

I went to

> Control Panel -> Programs and Features, right-clicked "Web Platform Installer" and chose "Repair"